# Help with a factorisation problem. Completely factor $4(a^2)(c^2) - (a^2 - b^2 + c^2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The questions asks to completely factor the following polynomial:

$4a^2c^2 - (a^2 - b^2 + c^2)^2$

The closest I can get to completely factoring it is (and I am not sure if this is even correct):

$2c^2(a^2 + b^2) - c^4 - a^4 - b^4 $

However the solution given is:

$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)$

This is a maths problem from the book [Precalculus Mathematics for Calculus](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Precalculus-Mathematics-Calculus-James-Stewart/dp/1305071751/ref=pd_sim_sbs_14_1?ie=UTF8&dpID=61-CJSOKdXL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR125%2C160_&refRID=HHM069WBTJ7WZGH0CTXS) (7th) Stewart, Lothar, Saleem Watson, page 35, exercises 1.3, number 133.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Expand the solution and you will have the original expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the factorization for the difference of two squares:
\begin{align*}
4a^2c^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2)^2&=(2ac+a^2-b^2+c^2)(2ac-a^2+b^2-c^2)\\
&=(a^2+2ac+c^2-b^2)(b^2-a^2+2ac-c^2)\\
&=\left[(a+c)^2-b^2\right]\left[b^2-(a-c)^2\right]\\
&=(a+c+b)(a+c-b)(b+(a-c))(b-(a-c))\\
&=\color{blue}{(a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)(-a+b+c)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood the steps you took to solve the equation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Squares difference: $\;x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)\;$ :

$$\overbrace{4a^2c^2}^{=(2ac)^2}-(a^2-b^2+c^2)^2=(2ac-(a^2-b^2+c^2))(2ac+(a^2-b^2+c^2))=$$

$$=\left(b^2-(a-c)^2\right)\left(-b^2+(a+c)^2\right)=(b-(a-c))(b+(a-c))(a+c-b)(a+c+b)$$

Now do some order inside with the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You answer and Angel really helped me.